# Why does clipping a line layer using a polygon result in an empty shapefile?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I am using QGIS 2.2.0 and want to clip a line layer (roads) so that only those inside a polygon are shown. When I do this using Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Clip I only get an empty shapefile as an output. I have tried transforming the original road shape file from multipart to singlepart before clipping and still have the same problem.

I've included a screenshot of what I am trying to do.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong or something to do differently?

[image: Clipping Line by Polygon]

Comment: Are you sure that road layer and polygon layer have the same CRS? If you turn `On-the-fly-reprojection` **OFF**, do they still align?

Comment: @AndreJoost you're right they don't align, but when I try to use the same CRS as the polygon layer (a user generated one) I have the problem that the two layers don't match anyway. Instead I used WGS 84 for the road layer to get them to display on the polygon. Maybe I should address this problem first...

Comment: Surely. If they don't align without on-the-fly-reprojection, clipping won't work.

Comment: @AndreJoost, I'm new to QGIS so please forgive me if my questions are obvious, but is there a way to to get the two layers to align?

Comment: What CRS do your layers have? What extent is reported under properties, metadata tab? What is your project CRS?

Comment: @AndreJoost, the polygon layer is user generated (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=30 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=5000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs) with extent xMin,yMin 373412.75,4696574.91 : xMax,yMax 463863.62,4833474.34. The road layer is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 with extent xMin,yMin 28.8732,-2.79098 : xMax,yMax 30.7831,-1.05456. The project works fairly well in either CRS, but I think it would be more appropriate to use the user generated one. Thank you!

Comment: try `vector - geoproccessing tool - intersects`.

Answer (score 5):

For the clipping of two layers, it is **mandatory** that both are stored to disk in the **same** CRS.

What you can do is:

1. Save the polygon layer with Rightclick -> `Save As ...` choose a new filename and WGS84 as CRS
2. Add the new shapefile to the canvas
3. remove the old polygon layer
4. clip the roads to the polygons

You can obviously do it the other way round too.